# Manually Cancel An Order

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.7

I have some orders that need to be cancelled but because they originally were pre-authorized through auth.net, they will not cancel. I get a "no transaction found" message when trying to cancel/void. Because of this I simply want to cancel the orders manually in the database and skip the standard void process. Does anyone know the specific tables in the Magento database that need to be modified to simply cancel an order?

Comment: You may also want to cancel the Order's Items. You may not need to though.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with this.
The Table in 1.7 is `sales_flat_order`. Columns are `state` and `status`.
Your going to what to set them both to `canceled`.
NOTE: You can use a select and where clause to verify names. This should work but I'm not 100% sure that it will not cause problems. I'm just answering your question.

You can really mess things up with this method so it would be smart to backup your database before you try anything.

GL

Comment: When I changed it to `cancelled`, the website showed a blank Order Status. But if I used `canceled`, it showed Order Status
Canceled. This is on Magento ver. 1.7.0.2. So not sure if it changed in the software or if SH made a typo.

Comment: Typo, I used the wrong spelling. Confirmed that the default internal magneto is canceled. Updating answer.

Comment: Okay cool. Voted up your answer. Just wanted to comment here and double check.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition here. If you are manually modify the order in the db as suggested above, you will also need modify the entry in table `sales_flat_order_grid`. Set `status` = `canceled`. Otherwise the order will appear as "Processing" in the grid view.