# cancel order with expired authorization transaction

Tags: magento, paypal, payment-gateway

How to cancel order with expired authorization transaction?
I tried to cancel order with expired authorization transaction in magento admin, but it fails with
error: Decline 10601 - Authorization has expired.
I tried to find record with txn_id in sales_payment_transaction table and to set it null.
But I still get message "Order has not been canceled".

Comment: Check out the answer seen here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631184/manually-cancel-an-order

Answer (score 1):

I could cancel the order with expired authorization transaction:

1. I took txn_id from order Sales -> Orders in magento admin.
2. Found record sales_payment_transaction with txn_id.
3. Changed field is_closed field from 0 to 1.
4. After these steps I could cancel order in magento admin.